# windbg output from !thread?

Tags: multithreading, kernel, windbg

Running windbg on a full memory dump. The !process command generates thread information (see below). Frequently the THREAD line is followed by multiple event-like things, like "fffffa800a0c0060  SynchronizationTimer". What do they signify? Are they objects the thread owns? Or is waiting on?

```
    THREAD fffffa8005718b50  Cid 16c0.1660  Teb: 00000000fffd8000 Win32Thread: 0000000000000000 WAIT: (UserRequest) UserMode Alertable
        fffffa800a0c0060  SynchronizationTimer
        fffffa800a7c1060  SynchronizationTimer
        <etc...>
        fffffa8007a9f4e0  SynchronizationEvent
        fffffa800ae48b20  SynchronizationTimer
    Not impersonating
    DeviceMap                 fffff8a01480f1e0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread doesn't really own objects, so it has to be the latter.

The documentation doesn't say this, but it's mentioned, for example, here: [How can I work out what events are being waited for with WinDBG in a kernel debug session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045759/how-can-i-work-out-what-events-are-being-waited-for-with-windbg-in-a-kernel-debu)